# Определение способа взаимодействия с Socket.IO клиентом в Android приложении

Tags: android, сеть, socket.io, android-service, eventbus

Продумываю сетевую архитектуру для Android приложения, которое использует Socket.IO клиент для связи с сервером. Из-за того, что фрагментов много, имеет смысл выделить для сокета отдельное место. Есть возможность сделать класс со статическим полем, но в таком случае имеем доступ к клиенту и высокую степень связности компонентов (coupling). Чтобы избавиться от такого варианта, думаю использовать `Service`, с сокет-клиентом внутри. А связь `Service` с  компонентами приложения организовать с помощью EventBus.
Вопрос больше в том, какой способ организации такого рода взаимодействия себя зарекомендовал на практике.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `Service` для работы с сокет соединением. Мы делали так проект, и все довольно удобно. Единственное не советую использовать EventBus, для этого можно использовать стандартный биндинг к `Service`

Comment: Почему Вы не рекомендуете EventBus? С ним возникают какие-то трудности?

Comment: Нет, Просто это считается как анти-паттерн. Логика непрозрачная становится